# Energy comparison of gas and electric automobiles

Tags: automotive-engineering, energy-efficiency

I'm trying to work out some comparisons of gas and electric automobiles, and am running into something that doesn't seem right to me. Let me explain:

Let's say a typical electric car has a range of 300 miles and requires 30 kWh to charge.
That works out to 100 Wh per mile traveled. This sounds reasonable — cruising at 60 mph on level ground would require about 6 kW, or about 8 hp, which agrees with numbers that I've heard elsewhere. Note that this figure includes the losses incurred in the proceses of charging and discharging the battery.

So how does this compare with my own gas car, which I consider to be reasonably efficient at 40 mpg on the average? I looked up the energy content of gasoline, which was given as 9500 Wh/l, or about 35 kWh/gal. But this would mean that my car is using 860 Wh worth of chemical energy per mile, more than 8× the energy of the electric car!

Are gas engines really that poor at converting chemical energy into mechanical energy? I was expecting to find a number in the range of 3× or 4×, but not 8×. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Better check your EV efficiency and include the efficiency of the charger, transmission lines, and your chosen powerplant.

Comment: @GregLocock also include energy use for petroleum extraction, refining and fuel transportation ... even the energy used to pump the fuel and to run a gas station

Comment: Yup that's about 83% efficient, from memory.

Comment: What about those people who run electric cars and they have solar panels producing the electricity used to charge the car/ Will you include all the "grey" energy required to produce the pv panels? If you do will you include the "grey" energy used to produce all the other power plants etc?

Comment: @SolarMike: I'm just looking at operating costs for the moment, ignoring nonrecurring costs just to keep things simpler. I know people like to jump immediately to the "big picture" in terms of economics and environmental effects, but that isn't what this question is about.

Comment: @GregLocock: I'm already including the charger, but not anything "upstream" of my power meter (generation and transmission). Is your 83% number efficiency, or loss?

Comment: An internal combustion engine is about 25% - 40% efficient in fuel terms, the volumetric efficiency is higher even exceeding 100% when turboed or supercharged. If you want to know more about engine efficiency then check out books by Cummins, Ricardo, Judge and others. Even check out some manufacturers as many things are explained. A better understanding might come from many Thermodynamics courses which have material online.

Comment: Energy has form and requires conversion from one to another, the cost of which may not be zero; I can have quite a lot of energy in terms of waste heat, but if it's spread over all of space, it costs to gather it.  If the starting point is your power meter, how much does it cost you to produce gasoline with the power meter? Similarly, if the starting point is gasoline, how much does ot cost to produce electricity for your EV? Ultimately, I suspect your starting point will be a form of currency...